# Go reading map from json stream

Tags: json, go

I need to parse really long json file (more than million items). I don't want to load it to the memory and read it chunk by chunk. There's a good example with the array of items [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode). The problem is that I deal with the map. And when I call `Decode` I get `not at beginning of value`.
I can't get what should be changed.

```golang
const data = `{
  "object1": {"name": "cattle","location": "kitchen"},
  "object2": {"name": "table","location": "office"}
}`

type ReadObject struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Location string `json:"location"`
}

func ParseJSON() {

    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))

    tkn, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to read opening token: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("opening token: %v\n", tkn)

    objects := make(map[string]*ReadObject)

    for dec.More() {

        var nextSymbol string
        if err := dec.Decode(&nextSymbol); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to parse next symbol: %v", err)
        }

        nextObject := &ReadObject{}

        if err := dec.Decode(&nextObject); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to parse next object")
        }

        objects[nextSymbol] = nextObject

    }

    tkn, err =  dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to read closing token: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("closing token: %v\n", tkn)

    fmt.Printf("OBJECTS: \n%v\n", objects)
}
```

Comment: you can load file chunk by chunk, manualy finding each element, extracting it and parsing it. Do you want me to demonstrate?

Comment: If you already have an example that will be nice. If no – no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL,DR: when you are calling `Token()` method for a first time, you move offset from the beginning (of a JSON value) and therefore you get the error.

You are working with this struct ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ebe77a2fda1ee9ff6fd9a3e08933ad1ebaea039/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L14)):

```
type Decoder struct {
    // others fields omits for simplicity
    tokenState int
}
```

Pay attention for a **tokenState** field. This value could be one of ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ebe77a2fda1ee9ff6fd9a3e08933ad1ebaea039/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L293)):

```
const (
    tokenTopValue = iota
    tokenArrayStart
    tokenArrayValue
    tokenArrayComma
    tokenObjectStart
    tokenObjectKey
    tokenObjectColon
    tokenObjectValue
    tokenObjectComma
)
```

Let's back to your code. You are calling `Token()` method. This method obtains first JSON-valid token `{` and changes **tokenState** from *tokenObjectValue*  to the *tokenObjectStart* ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ebe77a2fda1ee9ff6fd9a3e08933ad1ebaea039/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L402)). Now you are "in-an-object" state.

If you try to call `Decode()` at this point you will get an error (*not at beginning of value*). This is because allowed states of **tokenState** for calling `Decode()` are *tokenTopValue*, *tokenArrayStart*, *tokenArrayValue*, *tokenObjectValue*, i.e. "full" value, not part of it ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2ebe77a2fda1ee9ff6fd9a3e08933ad1ebaea039/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L337)).

To avoid this you can just don't call `Token()` at all and do something like this:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(dataMapFromJson))

objects := make(map[string]*ReadObject)
if err := dec.Decode(&objects); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to parse next symbol: %v", err)
}

fmt.Printf("OBJECTS: \n%v\n", objects)
```

Or, if you want to read chunk-by-chunk, you could keep calling `Token()` until you reach "full" value. And then call `Decode()` on this value (I guess this should work).

Answer (score 0):

After consuming the initial `{` with your first call to `dec.Token()`, you must :

- use `dec.Token()` to extract the next key
- after extracting the key, you can call `dec.Decode(&nextObject)` to decode an entry

example code :

```
    for dec.More() {
        key, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }

        var val interface{}
        err = dec.Decode(&val)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }

        fmt.Printf("  %s : %v\n", key, val)
    }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5r1d8MsNlKb